# Firebird connection on a local database impossible within a Python script

Tags: python, firebird, fdb

I can connect to my Firebird database using Firebird ISQL Tool (Firebird 3.0.4) with the following command:
`connect "C:\Documents\database.db" user 'USER' password 'PASSWORD';`

When I want to do it in a Python script (Python v3.7.7 on a Windows10 64 bits), in a virtual environment including fdb v2.0.1 or even firebirdsql v1.1.3, I can't and I systematically get an error.

```
import fdb
con = fdb.connect(database="C:\Documents\database.db", user='USER' password='PASSWORD'')
```

> DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE:
>   -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "xnet://Global\FIREBIRD".', -902, 335544721)

or

```
con = fdb.connect(host='localhost', database="D:\Documents\database.db", user= 'USER' password= 'PASSWORD'')
```

> DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE:
>   -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)

or

```
con = fdb.connect(dsn="localhost:C:\Documents\database.db", user='USER' password='PASSWORD'')
```

> DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE:
>   -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)

or

```
import firebirdsql
con = firebirdsql.connect(host='localhost', database="D:\Documents\database.db", user='USER' password='PASSWORD'')
```

If you have any idea you are welcome as I am stuck.

Comment: Do you have a Firebird database server running on your machine, and if not, did you include Firebird embedded with your program or put Firebird embedded on the path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error indicates that the `fbclient.dll` loaded by FDB does not provide Firebird Embedded, and that you don't have Firebird Server running on your machine.

To address this you must either:

1. Start Firebird Server (by starting its service or running `firebird -a`)
2. If you want to use Firebird Embedded instead of Firebird Server, point FDB to a `fbclient.dll` that provides Firebird Embedded

Point 2 can be done in several ways. In my answer I'm assuming use of Firebird 3 installed in `C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird-3.0.5.33220-0_x64`. Since Firebird 3, a normal Firebird Server install also provides Firebird Embedded. To point to a Firebird Embedded, you can do the following:

1. Add the Firebird installation directory to the `PATH` environment variable (make sure it is listed **before** `%SystemRoot\System32`/`C:\Windows\System32`). On a normal Firebird installation, the `fbclient.dll` without Firebird Embedded is installed in the `System32` folder, and if that gets loaded, you can't use Firebird Embedded.
2. Use `fdb.load_api` to load the client library:

   ```
   fdb.load_api('C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird-3.0.5.33220-0_x64/fbclient.dll')
   ```

   This needs to be done before the first use of `fdb.connect`, otherwise the library found through the normal search path will be used
3. Specify the client library using the `fb_library_name` connection property:

   ```
   con = fdb.connect(dsn='C:/path/to/yourdatabase.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey', 
       fb_library_name='C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird-3.0.5.33220-0_x64/fbclient.dll')
   ```

   This property needs to be specified on the first connection made using FDB. Although the existence of the property would suggest this is 'per connection', FDB will always use the first client library loaded (in essence, it works as if you called `load_api` just before the `connect`).

If you're using Firebird 2.5 or earlier, you will need to download the specific Firebird 2.5 Embedded package, and point to its `fbembed.dll` instead of `fbclient.dll`. For Firebird 2.5 Embedded, adding its location to the path will not work unless you rename or copy its `fbembed.dll` to `fbclient.dll`.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you very much. It works without changing anything (I've just tested Point 2)! GREAT!!!

Comment: @hganger You're welcome. If the answer fixed your problem, could you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was done when voting. Thank you again for this precise and detailed answer

Comment: @hganger Voting and accepting are separate steps: consider when you get multiple answers: you can upvote them all, but only accept one answer.